# How do I move a file to its parent's parent directory?

Tags: command-line

Consider something like `B/A/C.txt`.

How can I move the `C.txt` file to its parent's parent directory so the result would be `B/C.txt`?

Comment: The exact command depends on which directory you are currently in?

Comment: If you move the file from `B/A/C.txt` to `B/C.txt`, you're moving it to it's parent directory, not it's parent's parent directory.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu.com! In case you find an answer to help solve a problem don't forget to click either the grey ☑ or the up-pointing arrow/triangle to the left of the text.

Answer (score 7):

One way would be

```
mv B/A/C.txt B/
```

Or

```
cd B/A/
mv C.txt ..
```

Answer (score 2):

For educational purposes

`$ man bash`
Type `/` and fill in `^ +Parameter Expansion` then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Alternatively study the Bash guides at [www.tldp.org](http://www.tldp.org)

An example to study:

```
$ f="B/A/C.txt"
$ mkdir -p "${f%/*}"
$ touch "$f"
$ find "${f%%/*}"
...
$ mv "${f}" "${f%/*}/.."
$ find "${f%%/*}"
B
B/C.txt
B/A
```

*Please note: This is NOT a general answer, there are caveats; but might be consider to be very close to it.*

More to study, restarted from scratch:

```
$ f="B/A/C.txt"
$ mkdir -p "${f%/*}"
$ touch "$f"
$ ( cd ${f%/*} && mv ${f##*/} .. )
```

Answer (score 1):

on Linux terminal mv C.txt ../.. make the trick:

```
$ mkdir -p /tmp/A/B # create as a temporary dir
$ cd /tmp/A/B       # get into dir
$ pwd               # show were you are
/tmp/A/B
$ echo 'foo' > C.txt # create a file containing text foo
$ mv C.txt ../..     # move file into parent dir of parent dir
$ cd ../../          # get into there
$ pwd                # are we there?
/tmp
$ cat C.txt          # check your file.
foo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that by doing

`mv B/A/C.txt B/`

or

`mv B/A/C.txt B/C.txt`

or

```
cd B/A/
mv C.txt ..
```